# Incorporate a sql column value into the field name

Tags: sql-server-2012

I would like to reformat Table 1 to concatenate 'exam attempt #' into the column ID as shown in Table 2: using the sql query editor, if possible.

[SQL Server Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybO9E.jpg)

[Query output format preferred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fODdv.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to help the community understand better your example, e.g. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know ahead of time how many attempts there are, you can write it with a PIVOT:

```
SELECT 
        p.StudentID, 
        p.[1] AS ExamAttempt_1, 
        p.[2] AS ExamAttempt_2, 
        p.[3] AS ExamAttempt_3
   FROM #Scores s
   PIVOT (MIN(s.ExamScore) FOR s.ExamAttempt IN ([1], [2], [3])) p
;
```

The query assumes that the data is in a temp table #Scores.

If you don't, you can generate the PIVOT with dynamic SQL.  This is a little tricky.

```
DECLARE @ValueList NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ColumnList NVARCHAR(4000);
WITH Attempts AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
            ExamAttempt,
            CAST(ExamAttempt AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS AttemptStr
        FROM #Scores s
)
, Pretty AS
(
    SELECT ExamAttempt,
            '[' + AttemptStr + ']' AS ValueStr,
            '[' + AttemptStr + '] AS ExamScore_' + AttemptStr AS ColumnStr
        FROM Attempts
)
    SELECT
            @ValueList = COALESCE(@ValueList + ', ', '') + ValueStr,
            @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + ', ', '') + ColumnStr
        FROM Pretty
        ORDER BY ExamAttempt ASC
;
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
    'SELECT StudentId, '
    + @ColumnList
    + ' FROM #Scores s PIVOT (MIN(ExamScore) '
    + ' FOR ExamAttempt IN ( '
    + @ValueList
    + ')) p'
;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql;
```

The @Sql variable basically holds the text from the first code snippet, up to niceties.

Note that while this can be done in SQL, it would be cleaner to do the formatting in the host language.

Comment: I'm a sql newbie, so I will try your above sql code.  If you think of a simpler solution could you also post it?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please further explain your use of #Scores?  Do I need to create a local temporary variable?  Is there any way we could use the actual name of the table?  I used the above tsql in a new query in sql server

Comment: You can replace "#Scores" with the name of your table.  I didn't see a table name in the query.  Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure there isn't a radically simpler solution.  You need to do a PIVOT, and to make PIVOT flexible, you need to use dynamic SQL.